# Ordered pairs with 2 sets with some conditions

Tags: combinatorics

$\langle B,C\rangle$ such that $ |B|=|C|=2$ and $ B,C\subseteq A $ and $B \cap C=\emptyset $
where $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ when the number of ordered pairs B,C

Is equal to the number of words length $6$ such that the numbers 0,1,2 is repeated each twice exactly

I suppose : $6\choose 2$  $\times 2 \times 4\times 3$ (updated**)
It is true?
How can i generalize it ?

Comment: This isn’t group theory...

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle B,C\rangle,$ not $<B,C>.$ I edited this question accordingly.

Comment: How you generalize it depends on what you want to generalize.  You can just put enough elements in order to make the required number of ordered pairs, then cut them up into pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true.  Assuming $B,C$ are each ordered pairs, you can select $B$ in $6 \cdot 5$ ways, which matches your ${6 \choose 2}\cdot 2$.  You can then select $C$ in $4 \cdot 3=12$ ways, not $2$.  It is equivalent to choosing four items from $A$ in order without replacement.  The first two make $B$ and the other two make $C$.

If $B,C$ are two element subsets of $A$, divide by $4$ to ignore the order in each of $B,C$

Comment: So $6\times5\times 4\times 3$ and it is beacuse the intersection is empty and thus when i choose 1 the other needs to be different

Comment: And i meant generalize in a way that it is with terms not numbers but i think i got.it , but what about $<B,C>, <C,B>$ it is not included in the question ?

Comment: The first comment is correct.  I don't understand the second one.  $B$ and $C$ are ordered pairs.  Reversing the ordered pairs is counted separately.  For example, we can have $((1,2),(3,4))$ and $((3,4),(1,2))$ as two sets of ordered pairs.  Those are both counted.

Comment: This is was my question tank you

Comment: Shouldn’t the number of ways to select $B$ be $6·5/2!$? Since $B$ is a subset of size $2$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest:  I believe $B$ is an ordered pair, so we should not divide by $2!$  I think we are forming ordered pairs of ordered pairs.

Comment: It looks more like orders pairs of subsets to me, since the notation $|B|=2$ and $B\subset A$ is typically reserved for subsets. Same goes for $B\cap C=\varnothing$.